# PhoneGap navigator.compass.watchHeading freezes on iPhone. Is there a minimal frequency rate?

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, phonegap-build, compass

I'm running a three.js phonegap project on a iPhone 5s, which rotates the camera according to the compass heading readout. All works as it should, but for the freezing of the compass readout after 10 seconds. The app continues to work fine, but the function *rotateCameraWithCompass* isn't called anymore. Also there is no call to *compassError*. The *watchHeading* method seems to have frozen.

A frequency of 30 ms seemed realistic, or is this technically out of bounds

UPDATE: I lowered the frequency down to 100ms, still freezes after about 10 seconds.

```
function rotateCameraWithCompass( heading ) {
    camera.rotation.y = -1 * Math.toRad( heading.magneticHeading );
}

function compassError( compassError ) { console.log( 'Compass error: ' + compassError.code ); }

var watchID = navigator.compass.watchHeading( rotateCameraWithCompass, compassError, { frequency: 30 } );
```

Comment: I found a workaroud. Using the time frequency to call on the compass always freezes on iOS. Using a compass rotation degree filter instead works without problems. So instead of `{ frequency: 30 }` (set in ms), use `{ filter: 0.5 }` (set in degrees).

Answer (score 0):

Answer posted to Google Groups:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/OEZO1-0LMT4

**Read the docs Luke!**

iOS has quirks noted in the documentation:

> Only one watchHeading can be in effect at one time in iOS. If a
>   watchHeading uses a filter, calling getCurrentHeading or watchHeading
>   uses the existing filter value to specify heading changes. Watching
>   heading changes with a filter is more efficient than with time
>   intervals.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_plugins_pluginapis.md.html#Plugin%20APIs 
http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.device-orientation

Bottom line: Use the filter as described by *Jan*